# temperature converter using functions in c programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int converttemperature(int f,int c)

int main()
{
    int farenheit, celcius, upper, lower, step;

    upper=300; lower=0; step=20;
    farenheit=lower;

    while(farenheit<=upper) 
    {
       converttemperature(farenheit, celcius);
       printf("%d\t %d\n", farenheit, celcius);
       farenheit = farenheit+step;
    }
   
    return 0;
}

int converttemperature(int f, int c)
{ 
    int f,c;

    c = 5 * (f-32) / 9;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to add a question.

Comment: When asking other people to read your code, decent formatting is important as it increases readability.

Comment: Please enable all warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can do this via `-Wall -Wextra`. You should get some warning about local variable `f` hiding the parameter `f`.

Comment: Where do you initialize `celcius`and `f`?

Comment: @Gerhardh and `c`, too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Why do you pass `c` if you assign a value in the function and don't use any passed value? Not to mention that you hide `c` via local variable as well.

Comment: @SouravGhosh you're right, missed that one. But at least some value is assigned. ;)

Comment: BTW: You should use the return value of your function. Printing the unaltered parameter variables will not be very useful.

Comment: There's no need for the `c` argument to the function. You should write `celcius = converttemperature(fahrenheit);`

Comment: It seems like you need to read a good tutorial on functions. SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to know the basics.

Comment: @Barmar okay thank you. Just started programming and functions was causing a lot of trouble.

Comment: What you want is `printf("%d\t %d\n", farenheit, converttemperature(fahrenheit));`

Comment: Consider changing `converttemperature` into a something like `to_celsius`, `celsius_from_fahrenheit` or anything similar that documents itself. Also, an integral type like `int` may not be the best choice for this type of conversions, compared to a floating point type like `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int converttemperature(int f);

int main(void)
{
    int farenheit, celcius, upper, lower, step;

    upper=300; lower=0; step=20;
    farenheit=lower;

    while(farenheit<=upper) 
    {
      celcius = converttemperature(farenheit);
       printf("%d\t %d\n", farenheit, celcius);
       farenheit = farenheit+step;
    }
   
    return 0;
}

int converttemperature(int f)
{ 
    int c;
    c = 5 * (f-32) / 9;
    return c;
}
```